# Error in connection with PostgreSQL 12 by creating a datasource

Tags: postgresql, wildfly

I'm getting an exception while connecting to PostgreSQL 12 by creating a data source via wildfly admin console.

It works fine on my another machine which has PostgreSQL 9.5. and it seems to work fine when I connect without data-source.

```
  try (Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection(
            "jdbc:postgresql://127.0.0.1:5432/registrar", "postgres", "postgres")) {

        if (conn != null) {
            System.out.println("Connected to the database!");

            Statement statement = conn.createStatement();
            ResultSet rs = statement.executeQuery("Select * FROM public.user LIMIT 10");

            while(rs.next())
                System.out.println(rs.getString(2));

        } else {
            System.out.println("Failed to make connection!");
        }
```

But when I create a data-source like this:

[image]
and this the exception that I get when I try to test the connection from UI.

```
Request
{
    "address" => [
        ("subsystem" => "datasources"),
        ("data-source" => "RegistrarDS")
    ],
    "operation" => "test-connection-in-pool"
}

Response

Internal Server Error
{
    "outcome" => "failed",
    "failure-description" => "WFLYJCA0040: failed to invoke operation: WFLYJCA0047: Connection is not valid",
    "rolled-back" => true,
    "response-headers" => {"process-state" => "reload-required"}
}
```

Has anything changed in PostgreSQL 12? What could be the issue?

Comment: ?Does this help? https://superuser.com/a/1380673/598224

Answer (score 0):

Could be an issue with the datasource-class defined in your driver as described [here](https://issues.redhat.com/browse/WFLY-6157?_sscc=t) on issues.redhat.com

> If a datasource-class is defined then it takes precedence to create the datasource and as such it can only use connection-properties.
>
> Since there is not a single connection-url property for all drivers, you have to use connection-properties if you are defining the datasource-class.

Another thing you could try is to set "Connection Properties" instead of "Connection URL" and make sure you are using the correct/latest driver jar file.

Also check your Postgresql logs for further info on the exception..

-> https://www.postgresql.org/about/news/2000/